# Leer fichero JSON donde los nombres de los campos están en un array y los datos en otro, en Java

Tags: java, json, parser

Quisiera saber cómo puedo analizar este fichero JSON, donde los nombres de los campos están en un array y los datos en otro. Este esl el fichero JSON:

```
    {
      "fields": [{"type":"int","id":"_id"},{"info":{"notes":"aa"},"type":"numeric","id":"CodMunicipio"},{"info":{"notes":"bb"},"type":"text","id":"Municipi"},{"info":{"notes":"cc"},"type":"numeric","id":"Casos PCR+"},{"info":{"notes":"dd"},"type":"text","id":"Incidència acumulada PCR+"},{"info":{"notes":"ee"},"type":"numeric","id":"Casos PCR+ 14 dies"},{"info":{"notes":"ff"},"type":"text","id":"Incidència acumulada PCR+14"},{"info":{"notes":"gg"},"type":"numeric","id":"Defuncions"},{"info":{"notes":"hh"},"type":"text","id":"Taxa de defunció"}],
      "records": [
        [1,46001,"Pueblo A",103," 9884,84",0," 0,0",0," 0,0"],
        [2,46002,"Pueblo B",111," 7360,74",3," 198,94",2," 132,63"],
        [3,3001,"Pueblo C",11," 1740,51",0," 0,0",0," 0,0"],
        [4,3002,"Pueblo D",318," 6683,48",4," 84,07",8," 168,14"]
    ]}
```

He probado de todo, y lo que he visto no se ajusta a lo que busco. Agradezco de antemano vuestra ayuda.

Comment: Siempre el JSON retorna 9 variables o puede variar?

Comment: Retorna 9 variables. Son 9 campos.

Comment: no entiendo el problema. Aqui tienes dos valores: el contenido de "fields" define los campos que tienes, el nombre del campo (el valor de "id") y el tipo(el valor de "type"). Luego, el contenido de "records" es un array de esos datos....